# Can't get User's Avatar entity to remove it in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity, one-to-one

I have an User entity and an Avatar entity with a One to One relation :

```
//MyBundle/Entity/User.php

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Participso\UserBundle\Entity\Avatar", cascade={"remove", "persist"})
 */
protected $avatar;
```

And if the user already have an Avatar, i want to remove the previous one using this :

```
//MyBundle/Controller/UserController.php

if ($avatarForm->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    if($currentUser->getAvatar()){
        $em->remove($currentUser->getAvatar());
    }

    $currentUser->setAvatar($avatar);
    $em->persist($currentUser); //"cascade=persist" from User
    $em->flush();
}
```

And this:

```
//MyBundle/Entity/Avatar.php

/**
 * @ORM\PostRemove()
 */
public function removeUpload()
{
    $file = __DIR__.'/../../../../web/uploads/avatar/' . $this->fileName;
    unlink($file);
}
```

But when i do `var_dump($currentUser->getAvatar())`
I get an empty FileName, even if the file name exists in the database:

```
object(Proxies\__CG__\Participso\UserBundle\Entity\Avatar)[355]
    public '__initializer__' => 
object(Closure)[348]
    public '__cloner__' => 
object(Closure)[349]
    public '__isInitialized__' => boolean false
    private 'id' (Participso\UserBundle\Entity\Avatar) => int 20
    public 'file' => null
    private 'fileName' (Participso\UserBundle\Entity\Avatar) => null
```

And when I do `var_dump($currentUser->getAvatar()->getFileName)`, I get the file name !! (and not NULL as seen previously)...

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: I think, this is `$em->remove($currentUser->getAvatar());` working for entity only.

Comment: Thank you, in fact getAvatar should return the Avatar entity, but i don't get why it doesnt'...

Comment: Try flushing after in the `if` block after the `$em->remove()`.

Comment: I can't, it's the foreing key of User : "ERROR:Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your replies !

In fact it's because of the "lazy loading" of doctrine :

If i do :

```
var_dump($currentUser->getAvatar());exit;
```

output :

```
object(Proxies\__CG__\Participso\UserBundle\Entity\Avatar)[355]
    private 'id' (Participso\UserBundle\Entity\Avatar) => int 20
    private 'fileName' (Participso\UserBundle\Entity\Avatar) => null
```

But if i do

```
$whatever = $currentUser->getAvatar()->getFileName();
var_dump($currentUser->getAvatar());exit;
```

output :

```
object(Proxies\__CG__\Participso\UserBundle\Entity\Avatar)[355]
    private 'id' (Participso\UserBundle\Entity\Avatar) => int 20
    private 'fileName' (Participso\UserBundle\Entity\Avatar) => string 'd4e5eadd3757498a22b14ad1f81869c2baf459d3.png'
```

This is pretty annoying... I'll create a new post to fix this.

**EDIT :** The new post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31764611/4391692), and it's resolved :

To avoid lazy loading from doctrine, just add `fetch="EAGER"` in your parent Entity :

```
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", fetch="EAGER")
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if($currentUser->getAvatar()){
       $currentUser->removeUpload();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but even if the file is deleted, the database line still exists... Ah and it's $currentUser->getAvatar()->removeUpload(); :)