# Select multiple entries of one Doctrine 2 entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Ok, lets suppose I have 2 types of entities: Gallery and Model. The Gallery class has a many to many field named "models" pointing to Model class, and the Model class has the "galleries" field pointing to Gallery.

What I need is to make a selection the result of which would be an array containing the models entities in the order they appear in the galleries.

For example if there are 2 different Galleries pointing to the same model, in the result array I need to have the corresponding Model entity twice.

Something like this:

```
$em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('g.models')
    ->from('\Gallery g')
    ->join(g.model m)
    ->orderBy(g.date)); //This does not work.
```

Or:

```
$em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('m')
    ->from('\Gallery g')
    ->join(g.models m)
    ->orderBy(g.date)); //This does not work either.
```

Comment: Do you really need the same entity twice? That looks like very clear sign of bad design - entities are as they name shows - single beings living in your application, why would you need the same entity twice?

Comment: I would rather argue that Doctrine cant do that kind of work because the design of ORMs are exactly to not let you got the same entity more than once

Comment: Hi Jacek. I really need them twice ( bad design - very possible, but still need them twice ).  @Jacek Dziurdzikowski

Comment: Can you describe why do you need the same entity twice? Maybe I can figure out how to avoid that or better solution because as I wrote - I dont think it is possible to have the same entity twice using Doctrine. Also I used bad words - its not about bad design - the whole idea of entity is to have only one.

Comment: It is a clients requirement. He wants to see the list of models as i described. If the model is in several galleries, he wants to see them in the list so much times, as they are encountered in galleries. @Jacek Dziurdzikowski

Comment: Ohh, okay, I got you then, I will try to figure out something

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$dql = 'SELECT g, m FROM Gallery g JOIN g.models m ORDER BY g.date ASC'


$galleries = $entityManager->createQuery($dql)
                           ->getResult();
```

Don't forget about proper FQCN of your entities, because above it looks like you do mistakes when naming your entities, once using 'models', other time single form - 'model'.

Comment: Didn't work. It returns an array of Gallery entities. No Model entities in result.

Comment: It seems really imposible. I think the solution well be to get the galleries  and then in a foreach get the models :((

Comment: No, this is called lazy loading and that is how the doctrine works, of course it is possible - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31763867/avoid-lazy-loading-doctrine-symfony2

Comment: Try use 'EAGER' as said in the linked answer

Comment: Was trying different variants for fetch="EAGER", but didn't work :((

Comment: Apparently you doing mistake somewhere in the whole process, I can't help without more details :( When you ask question, try to provide as many details as you can, also screenshots of the object's structures you get in response

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Will use the variant with foreach. If anybody had similar problem / task, or just has a solution, maybe will be helpfull to post it here.